# Where to configure disk pressure in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a master node that has disk pressure and is spamming the log full with endless messages like these:

> Mar 18 22:53:04 kubelet[7521]: W0318 22:53:04.413211    7521 eviction_manager.go:344] eviction manager: attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage
>
> Mar 18 22:53:04 kubelet[7521]: I0318 22:53:04.413235    7521 container_gc.go:85] attempting to delete unused containers
>
> ......................
>
> Mar 18 22:53:04  kubelet[7521]: E0318 22:53:04.429446    7521 eviction_manager.go:574] eviction manager: cannot evict a critical pod kube-controller-manager_kube-system(5308d5632ec7d3e588c56d9f0bca17c8)
> Mar 18 22:53:04  kubelet[7521]: E0318 22:53:04.429458    7521 eviction_manager.go:574] eviction manager: cannot evict a critical pod kube-apiserver_kube-system(9fdc5b37e61264bdf7e38864e765849a)
> Mar 18 22:53:04  kubelet[7521]: E0318 22:53:04.429464    7521 eviction_manager.go:574] eviction manager: cannot evict a critical pod kube-scheduler_kube-system(90280dfce8bf44f46a3e41b6c4a9f551)
> Mar 18 22:53:04  kubelet[7521]: E0318 22:53:04.429472    7521 eviction_manager.go:574] eviction manager: cannot evict a critical pod coredns-74ff55c5b-th722_kube-system(33744a13-8f71-4e36-8cfb-5955c5348a14)
> Mar 18 22:53:04  kubelet[7521]: E0318 22:53:04.429478    7521 eviction_manager.go:574] eviction manager: cannot evict a critical pod coredns-74ff55c5b-d45hd_kube-system(65a5684e-5013-4683-aa38-820114260d63)
> Mar 18 22:53:04  kubelet[7521]: E0318 22:53:04.429487    7521 eviction_manager.go:574] eviction manager: cannot evict a critical pod weave-net-wjs78_kube-system(f0f9a4e5-98a4-4df4-ac28-6bc1202ec06d)
> Mar 18 22:53:04  kubelet[7521]: E0318 22:53:04.429493    7521 eviction_manager.go:574] eviction manager: cannot evict a critical pod kube-proxy-8dvws_kube-system(c55198f4-38bc-4adf-8bd8-4a2ec2d8a46d)
> Mar 18 22:53:04  kubelet[7521]: E0318 22:53:04.429498    7521 eviction_manager.go:574] eviction manager: cannot evict a critical pod etcd_kube-system(e3f86cf1b5559dfe46a5167a548f8a4d)
> Mar 18 22:53:04  kubelet[7521]: I0318 22:53:04.429502    7521 eviction_manager.go:396] eviction manager: unable to evict any pods from the node
>
> ..............

This has been going on for months. I know that disk pressure is probably set the default value, but WHERE is it configured in the first place?

I do know about this:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/

It is probably this setting that can be set:

`imagefs.available  imagefs.available := node.stats.runtime.imagefs.available`

(according to the link above)

But again, where? In `etcd`? How can I set this for all nodes to a default?

It is true that there is less space available than the setting is set to, but this is the controlplane (there are no other pods on it) and not a productive system, it is for testing only and I can't see anything in the logs because kubernetes spams it full of garbage. Garbage because these messages make absolutely not sense:
These pods are not supposed to be evicted ever, they are essential and they should not even be tried to evict.

My questions:

- Also, what about the rate limiter?
- Of stopping after it failing 10 times?
- Crashloopbackoff?
- Also, I can't see the currently set values.

Answer (score 2):

There's three ways to set Kubelet options. First is [command line options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) like `--eviction-hard`. Next is a [config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/). And more recent is [dynamic configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/).

Of course the better answer here is to free up some disk space.

Comment: No, freeing up disk space is avoiding the question of how to configure this, it is not the proper solution. It is also not relevant, the threshold for disk pressure is set too conservatively, again, this is not a productive system and it is in no danger of becoming instable because of too little diskspace.

Comment: Sure, which is why I answered the question first with three different options.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to include imagefs.available in the yaml config for the kubelet, but there are key pairs, this one needs 3 elements: 1. imagefs.available   2. equal or smaller / larger than      3. the size value.

Comment: How do you query currently set values for these pressure setting? Is there a way at all?

Comment: The "dynamic configuration" link is broken

Comment: The feature was removed https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/11/18/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-26/#removal-of-dynamic-kubelet-configuration